# SQL Server Analysis Services 2005 crash when disk is full?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server

One of our SQL boxes ran itself out of disk space last night.  This particular server has both the database engine and analysis services on it.  Database engine was not happy about having no disk space on the volume where all the data files are, but analysis services just plain died.

At least, the only thing I have to blame is the full volume.  Has anyone experienced a SSAS that they've been able to directly tie to no disk space?  I've got nothing else in the SQL or event logs to blame...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All kinds of SQL services will not behave nicely when the disk gets full.  The main problem is that SQL uses caching extensively and that usually means disk space.  Sql Server loves it's disk space!  Our fun with this is with SRS.  It the disk gets full, the reports blow up with a web page error.